# Equation in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Solving the following exercise of a list I have: "$H$ is a complex Hilbert space admitting an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}, n\in \mathbb{N}$ ; $\{\lambda_n\}\subset \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ is a sequence such that $\{|\lambda_n|\}$ is decreasing and tends to zero. Prove that $T(e_n) = \lambda_ne_n$  defines a continuous, one-to-one linear function $T$ of $H$ in itself ". I have solved this and I am interested now in the related question:

> Find the solutions of the equation $T(x) - \alpha x = y$, where $\alpha$ is a complex cube root of 1 and $y$ is fixed in $H$.

Comment: I have made some formatting changes to your post; please take not of what I did so that you know how to make your questions more readable in the future.

Comment: It may help to rewrite the equation as
$$
(T - \alpha \,\text{id})(x) = y
$$
What we're looking for is an eigenvector of $T$ associated with $\alpha$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom:  wouldn't an eigenvector satisfy $(T - \alpha \;\text{id})(x) = 0$, so any two solutions to $(T - \alpha \;\text{id})(x) = y$ differ by an eigenvector (in this case)?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks. By the way, I am going to learning writing in English and Tex Commands. It is hard for me, I beg you all people of math.stackexchange for your tolerance with my bad English

Comment: @RobertLewis ahhhh whoops!  Don't know what I was thinking there.  *ahem* I mean, that's what I meant. Yep.

Comment: @Robert Lewis Take into account that T is assumed to be 1-1

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez just because $T$ is 1-1, doesn't mean that $T - \alpha \text{id}$ will be as well.  In fact, $T - \alpha \text{id}$ will be 1-1 if (and only if) $\alpha\notin \{\lambda_n\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $x = \sum_{n \in \Bbb N} {x_n e_n}$, then
$$
T x - \alpha x = \sum_{n \in \Bbb N} (\lambda_n - \alpha)x_n e_n
$$
Now, if $y = \sum_{n \in \Bbb N} y_n e_n$, use the above to solve for each $x_n$.

That is, we have
$$
(\lambda_n - \alpha)x_n = y_n
$$
If $\lambda_n \neq \alpha$ for every $n$, then we can define $x$ by
$$
x_n = \frac{y_n}{\lambda_n - \alpha}
$$
If $\lambda_n = \alpha$ but $y_n \neq 0$, then there is no solution for $x$.
If $\lambda_n = \alpha$ but $y_n = 0$, then we'll have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: So x is unique provide that any $\lambda_n$ is equal to $\alpha$ ?

Comment: $x$ exists and is unique provided that **none of the** $\lambda_n$ is equal to $\alpha$.

Comment: @sasha  Are you suggesting that T - $\alpha$I is not 1-1?

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez it is not 1-1 if $\lambda_n = \alpha$ for some $n$.

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez I made a arithmetic mistake edited it

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have interpreted "any" as "none of the" (which I believe is correct in English).

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez "any" means "some of the", which is quite the opposite.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I accept as satisfactory your answer, (on the other hand, what is "in any case"? Besides many dictionnaries of English-Spanish traslated "any" by both, "alguno" and  "ninguno"). Regards.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom the unknomn is x not its components

Comment: "In any case" means the same as "anyway".  Google translates it as "de todos modos"; perhaps this is a better translation.

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez if you know $x$ then you know its components and vice versa.

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez the fact that "any" can be both "alguno" (some, usually) and "ninguno" (none, usually) has to do with how Spanish/English handle negatives.  "Yo **no** tengo **ningún** calcetines" would be translated either as "I **don't** have any socks".  In Spanish, there's a "double negative"; in English, you only say "no" once.